# /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `(' and other strange errors

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, cmake, clion

I have a very strange error compiling my C++ code.

Situation: I have a big project that uses PCL, OpenCV, VTK, ANN... and is actually working on Linux.

Now, I'm trying to set up the project in MAC OSX but there are some problems. I installed all needed libraries, and it seems that all dependencies are linked but when I try to compile the project some strange errors appears:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++   -DDISABLE_OPENNI -DEIGEN_USE_NEW_STDVECTOR -DEIGEN_YES_I_KNOW_SPARSE_MODULE_IS_NOT_STABLE_YET -DFLANN_STATIC -DvtkDomainsChemistry_AUTOINIT="1(vtkDomainsChemistryOpenGL2)" -DvtkRenderingContext2D_AUTOINIT="1(vtkRenderingContextOpenGL2)" -DvtkRenderingCore_AUTOINIT="3(vtkInteractionStyle,vtkRenderingFreeType,vtkRenderingOpenGL2)" -DvtkRenderingVolume_AUTOINIT="1(vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL2)" -pg -g -I/usr/local/include/vtk-6.3 -I/usr/local/lib/ann_1.1.2/include -I/usr/local/include/pcl-1.6 -I/usr/local/include/eigen3 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/flann/1.8.4_1/include -I/usr/local/include/opencv    vtkDomainsChemistry_AUTOINIT=1(vtkDomainsChemistryOpenGL2) vtkRenderingContext2D_AUTOINIT=1(vtkRenderingContextOpenGL2) vtkRenderingCore_AUTOINIT=3(vtkInteractionStyle,vtkRenderingFreeType,vtkRenderingOpenGL2) vtkRenderingVolume_AUTOINIT=1(vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL2)  -msse4.1 -mfpmath=sse -o CMakeFiles/Pipeline.dir/main.cpp.o -c /Users/ferran/ViCOROB/PROJECTS/Pipeline/main.cpp'
make[3]: /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++   -DDISABLE_OPENNI -DEIGEN_USE_NEW_STDVECTOR -DEIGEN_YES_I_KNOW_SPARSE_MODULE_IS_NOT_STABLE_YET -DFLANN_STATIC -DvtkDomainsChemistry_AUTOINIT="1(vtkDomainsChemistryOpenGL2)" -DvtkRenderingContext2D_AUTOINIT="1(vtkRenderingContextOpenGL2)" -DvtkRenderingCore_AUTOINIT="3(vtkInteractionStyle,vtkRenderingFreeType,vtkRenderingOpenGL2)" -DvtkRenderingVolume_AUTOINIT="1(vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL2)" -pg -g -I/usr/local/include/vtk-6.3 -I/usr/local/lib/ann_1.1.2/include -I/usr/local/include/pcl-1.6 -I/usr/local/include/eigen3 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/flann/1.8.4_1/include -I/usr/local/include/opencv    vtkDomainsChemistry_AUTOINIT=1(vtkDomainsChemistryOpenGL2) vtkRenderingContext2D_AUTOINIT=1(vtkRenderingContextOpenGL2) vtkRenderingCore_AUTOINIT=3(vtkInteractionStyle,vtkRenderingFreeType,vtkRenderingOpenGL2) vtkRenderingVolume_AUTOINIT=1(vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL2)  -msse4.1 -mfpmath=sse -o CMakeFiles/Pipeline.dir/data.cpp.o -c /Users/ferran/ViCOROB/PROJECTS/Pipeline/data.cpp'
*** [CMakeFiles/Pipeline.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 2
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Pipeline.dir/data.cpp.o] Error 2
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Pipeline.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Pipeline.dir/rule] Error 2
```

I searched through the Internet, but I couldn't find any reference for this specific problem.

Any suggestion?

Comment: It seems that shell doesn't understand some code, generated by CMake. What shell is used? (`/bin/sh` is just a link to actuall shell).

Comment: Are you trying to run your C code without compiling it?

Comment: Actually, I use Clion as a IDE and I use it to compile and run the code. However, I tried "manually" in the terminal, using the default shell, and also $bash and $sh, and I always obtain the same error.